# How to create a bean of executor services in Spring using XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have to create a bean of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` in a Spring configuration file that is written in XML. In Java, I would write it as

```
@Bean(name = "MyThreadPoolList")
    public List<ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor> executorList() {
        List<ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor> executor = new ArrayList<>();
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor tempExecutor;
        for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++ ){
            tempExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(
                    1,
                    NamingThreadFactory.createWithDaemon("ExecutorPool-"+i+"-Thread-%d", true));
            tempExecutor.prestartAllCoreThreads();
            executor.add(i, tempExecutor);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(executor);
    }
```

But I don't know what's the best way to achieve this in XML. I can try something like following:

```
<bean id="MyThreadPoolList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" init-method="prestartAllCoreThreads">
                 <constructor-arg value="1"/>
                 <constructor-arg>
                     <bean class="my.factory.NamingThreadFactory" factory-method="createWithDaemon">
                           <constructor-arg value="ExecutorPool-0-Thread-%d"/>
                           <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true"/>
                     </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" init-method="prestartAllCoreThreads">
                 <constructor-arg value="1"/>
                 <constructor-arg>
                     <bean class="my.factory.NamingThreadFactory" factory-method="createWithDaemon">
                           <constructor-arg value="ExecutorPool-1-Thread-%d"/>
                           <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true"/>
                     </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" init-method="prestartAllCoreThreads">
                 <constructor-arg value="1"/>
                 <constructor-arg>
                     <bean class="my.factory.NamingThreadFactory" factory-method="createWithDaemon">
                           <constructor-arg value="ExecutorPool-2-Thread-%d"/>
                           <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true"/>
                     </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But the problems are:

1. there is too much duplicate code and
2. if in future, I want to increase the number of executor services to 500, I will have to copy this 500 times.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't have to keep your code in XML config files, right?  Even if you start with an XML config, you could switch to an annotation-aware application context, and add a context:component-scan tag in your XML file - and you could keep this part of your config as you have in, in Java config...

Comment: Thinking of wanting 500 executors, each with its own thread pool, sounds suspicious...

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your suggestion. Do you have any example?

500 executors will probably never be required. Maximum I will go up to 10. Right now I am just trying to sneak in some improvement by making minimum amount of change to the code base. If I ever have to go to 500, the code will have to be refactored.